# Find next quarter end date given previous quarter end date using Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, apache-commons-dateutils

I am having quarter end date of last quarter let it be `30-09-20` , the requirement is to find end date of next quarter i.e `31-12-20`. I am using below code to do the same but is it giving wrong output in some scenarios. This solution should be correct for all quarters.

```
String str = "30-09-20";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Date date = format.parse(str);
Date newDate = DateUtils.addMonths(date, 3);
System.out.println(newDate);//Dec 30 - It should be 31 Dec
```

Comment: How are your quarters defined? Are they fix dates?

Comment: January, February, and March (Q1)- Will pick last date of March
April, May, and June (Q2)-Will pick last date of June
July, August, and September (Q3)
October, November, and December (Q4)

Comment: wouldn't the quarter always be constant? There are only 4 quarters and they all have fixed end dates i.e., 31st March, 30th June, 30th Sept and 31st Dec?

Comment: If you have if `01-09-20` what should be the result?

Comment: But year won't be constant . If I hit on 31st Dec , 2020 it should return 31stMarch,2021.

Comment: So the problem is execution on a day that already is the end of a quarter and you want the end of the upcoming one?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Don’t represent your date as a string. Represent it as a `LocalDate`. A string is fine for printing a result to the user, but not for processing inside your program. So only format into a string when you need to give output.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer your question, I think you are looking for this :

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");
LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("30-09-20", formatter)
    .plusMonths(3)                             // add three months to your date
    .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()); // with the last day of the month
```

Note: don't use the legacy Date library, you tagged your question Java-8 which mean you can use [java-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) API.

---

### Get last day of current quarter

[@deHaar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59946969/find-next-quarter-end-date-given-previous-quarter-end-date-using-java/59947183#comment106014531_59947183) have reason, to get the end date of curent quarter, I would suggest to use :

```
public LocalDate lastDayFromDateQuarter(String date) {
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    int quarter = ld.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR); // Get the Quarter, 1, 2, 3, 4
    // Then create a new date with new quarter * 3 and last day of month
    return ld.withMonth(quarter * 3).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
}
```

### Get last day of next quarter

To get the last day of the next quarter, then you just can add three months to your date like so :

```
public static LocalDate lastDayFromDateQuarter(String date) {
    final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    int quarter = ld.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR);
    return ld.withMonth(quarter * 3)
            .plusMonths(3)
            .with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that return a wrong date when the current one isn't in April, July, September or December because you always add 3 months?

Comment: @deHaar I agree, I gives you an answer in my edit, hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Yes, `IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR` is the way to go... Had upvoted before, cannot do again ;-)

Comment: Nice. As a detail I’d use `return ld.plus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());`. I would probably also add validation that the incoming date is indeed the last day of a quarter.

Comment: @Boris I think your test is not correct, In fact `30-12-20` is the last day of the 3rd quarter for that it return the same result, I can say that the first solution answer the OP problem in a part and the correct general solution should be the second

Comment: @YCF_L, your proposed solution fails this test: `@ParameterizedTest
  @CsvSource({"30-09-20,2020-12-31"})
  public void testLastDayFromDateQuarter(String input, LocalDate expected) {
    LocalDate result = timeUtils.lastDayFromDateQuarter(input);
    assertEquals(expected, result);
  }` **Test result:** AssertionFailedError: expected: <2020-12-31> but was: <2020-09-30>

Comment: @Boris check this https://www.motif.com/faq/what-are-the-beginning-and-end-dates-for-each-quarter

Comment: @YCF_L, from the question: "the requirement is to find end date of next quarter i.e 31-12-20", is it not right?

Comment: @Boris I will check when I back at home :)

Comment: @OleV.V. I test your code, but it doesn't return the correct result, I don't know what did you mean exactly or how should I use your code

Comment: @Boris I edit my answer, can you check it now please, thank you for your test :)

Comment: @YCF_L It’s not important, your answer is accepted and everything, but since you ask (at least to me it sounded like a question) [this is what I meant](https://ideone.com/O62Qx0).

Comment: @YCF_L, now it's fine, the test passed.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Use [`YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class from [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/).

```
YearQuarter                                       // A class available in the ThreeTen-Extra library.
.from(                                            // Factory method rather than calling `new`. 
    LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 30 )   // Returns a `LocalDate` object, represent a date-only value without a time-of-day and without a time zone.
)                                                 // Returns a `YearQuarter` object.
.plusQuarters( 1 )                                // Perform date-math, resulting in a new `YearQuarter` object (per immutable objects pattern). 
.atEndOfQuarter()                                 // Determine the date of last day of this year-quarter.
.toString()                                       // Generate text in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

> 2020-12-31

## `org.threeten.extra.YearQuarter`

The [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library provides classes that extend the functionality of the *java.time* classes built into Java 8 and later. One of its classes is `YearQuarter` to represent a specific quarter in a specific year. The quarters are defined by calendar-year: Jan-Mar, Apr-June, July-Sept, Oct-Dec.

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 30 ) ;
YearQuarter yearQuarter = YearQuarter.from( localDate ) ;
```

Move to the next quarter by adding one quarter to our current year-quarter.

The *java.time* and *ThreeTen-Extra* classes use immutable objects. So rather than alter ("mutate") the original object, when adding we produce a new object.

```
YearQuarter followingYearQuarter = yearQuarter.plusQuarters( 1 ) ;
```

Determine the last day of that quarter.

```
LocalDate lastDateOfFollowingYearQuarter = followingYearQuarter.atEndOfQuarter() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version (hopefully more readable) of finding the last day of next quarter for any date:

```java
public LocalDate lastDayOfNextQuarter(LocalDate date) {
  Month firstMonthOfCurrentQuarter = date.getMonth().firstMonthOfQuarter();
  LocalDate lastMonthOfCurrentQuarter = date.with(firstMonthOfCurrentQuarter.plus(2));
  LocalDate lastMonthOfNextQuarter = lastMonthOfCurrentQuarter.plusMonths(3);
  return lastMonthOfNextQuarter.with(lastDayOfMonth());
}
```

And a corresponding test method:

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"2020-01-01,2020-06-30", "2020-02-01,2020-06-30", "2020-03-01,2020-06-30", "2020-04-10,2020-09-30",
  "2020-05-10,2020-09-30", "2020-06-10,2020-09-30", "2020-07-20,2020-12-31", "2020-08-20,2020-12-31",
  "2020-09-30,2020-12-31", "2020-10-30,2021-03-31", "2020-11-30,2021-03-31", "2020-12-31,2021-03-31"})
public void testLastDayOfNextQuarter(LocalDate input, LocalDate expected) {
  LocalDate result = timeUtils.lastDayOfNextQuarter(input);
  assertEquals(expected, result);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate quarter easily with TemporalAdjusters. See below:

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate firstDayOfQuarter = localDate.with(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1);
    System.out.println(firstDayOfQuarter);

    LocalDate lastDayOfQuarter = firstDayOfQuarter.plusMonths(2).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(lastDayOfQuarter);

    LocalDate firstDateOfNextQuarter = lastDayOfQuarter.plusDays(1);

    LocalDate lastDayOfNextQuarter = firstDateOfNextQuarter.plusMonths(2).with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
    System.out.println(lastDayOfNextQuarter);
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01
2020-03-31
2020-06-30
```

Comment: You can also have a LocalDate on the first day of next quarter like this `LocalDate.now().plus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS).with(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, 1)`. I find this method very convenient if you want to "move" by multiple quarters at once and it will handle the change of year.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getActualMaximum-int-) instance to get the last day of the month.

```
String str = "30-12-20";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Date date = format.parse(str);
Date newDate = DateUtils.addMonths(date, 3);

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTime(newDate);

System.out.println(cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```